# Error when installing ubuntu touch developer preview

Tags: android, ubuntu-touch

I installed Ubuntu Phone OS on my Galaxy Nexus. At the last steps an error occured:

```
Pushing /home/cesare/Scaricati/phablet-flash/95/quantal-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip to /sdcard/
protocol failure
Error while excetuting adb push /home/cesare/Scaricati/phablet-flash/95/quantal-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip /sdcard/
Make sure the device is connected and viewable by running 'adb devices'
Ensure you have a root device, one which running 'adb root' does not return an error
cesare@ubuntu:~$
```

What can I do?

Update

I have enabled usb debugging ecc...

Comment: Not sure, but have you rooted/unlocked it (probably silly question), enabled  usb debugging? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install . Join the irc , they may help you faster

Comment: Ensure you have a root device

Answer (score 1):

When I ran the "`phablet-flash -b`" command, it had failed during a push operation with protocol error. This occurred when the image that was downloaded was being pushed to the android device as `autodeploy.zip`.  Since `autodeploy.zip` is likely corrupt at this point, it will cause various symptoms.

The best thing to do is to look for that protocol error, and repeat the push operation by running a command similar to the following:

```
adb push /home/<user>/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130705.1/saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip
```

Once I rebooted in recovery mode, things went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when on the bootloader screen, but it works when in Recovery Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I get similar errors often, depending on which USB cable I use. Some cables work fine, other give problems like this (even if the cable does not appear to be broken, I get disconnected from the device often), so try another (shorter?) cable.